# How to stop mesh getting into another mesh

Tags: animation, mesh

I want to make a simple animation of a cube rotating and going to another place. But when it rotates the cube sinks into the mesh under the cube. How to stop it from happening.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Blender will not automatically handle these. One solution is to setup Softbody simulation. Another solution, simplest I think is to use Shape keys.